# layout_above of Relative layout in Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Here is my code and I want ViewPager to above LinearLayout and below ImageView. It is coming below ImageView but overlaps LinearLayout. I tried layout_constarintBottom_toTopOf property but it's not working. Which property use correctly to solve this issue

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_app_logo"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_registration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_get_started"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/get_started_text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_app_logo"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you need to set atleast 2 constraint one for top bottom one for left right.

Comment: can you please explain with code, I am new to constraint layout so not getting exactly what you are saying

Comment: you should keep in mind, that constraint layout is designed to be used in the 'Design' tab not in the 'Text' tab of the xml file. 
I'd recommend you to watch a tutorial like this one first: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N4bCdyGcUc

Comment: @Distra okay. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this...

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_app_logo"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear_layout_registration"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_app_logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_registration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_get_started"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/get_started_text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use match_constraint property for view pager height from design tab->attributes. It will adjust view pager according to its constraints.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_app_logo"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_registration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_get_started"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="get started"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_app_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linear_layout_registration"/>
```